# Div onmouseout with images inside , how to make this work without "getting out" the div every time i select a image?

Tags: php, javascript, html, onmouseout

my problem is "simple" , i have a div with a onmouseout property with an alert("1"), that div have 2 images inside, everytime i select a image that alert show up.

example.

```
<div onmouseout="alert(1)">
<img src="imgs/image1.png"  onmouseover="loadimg(this)" id=image1>
 <img src="imgs/image2.png"  onmouseover="loadimg(this)" id=image2>
</div>
```

i want to show that alert only if my mouse get out of all div , this div should include images too.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) in jQuery. [Here's a demo of it](http://jsfiddle.net/XKBAt/1/) in jsfiddle.

If you want to avoid using jQuery, have a look at [this discussion on comp.lang.javascript](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_thread/thread/174b670db5916966/45bbef24b5ad0de1?q=bubbling&rnum=1&pli=1) on a similar subject.